# Как правильно представить if-else- блок в Unit Test?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте.
Я хочу с помощью `Unit Test` проверить, или моя функция правильно работает и не знаю как заменить блок `if-else`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_CreateDatabase()
{
    String database = "test_db";
    Program.CreateDatabase(@"C:\Temp\create_database.sql", database);
    String sqlConnectionString = String.Format("Server = server; 
        Database = {0}; Trusted_Connection = True;", database);

    String countTables = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables ";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
        var result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(countTables);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            bool temp = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool temp = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В модульных тестах VS используются методы `Assert.IsNull`, `Assert.AreEqual`, `Assert.IsTrue` и т.д. Если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите, то ваш метод `Assert.AreNotEqual`.

Comment: Что именно проверяет ваш тест? Что в базе есть таблицы? Тогда `Assert.IsTrue(result > 0, "Expected to have some tables");`.

Comment: Тест проверяет, или табоицы были добавленны в базу даных. Если таблицы добавленны, `result =1`. Следует, если таблицы добавленны, то условие `Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToInt32(result), 1)` будет `true`. Если же  условие `Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToInt32(result), 1)` не будет выполнено, то  `Test failed`. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да, правильно. Только учтите, что ваш тест не проверяет состав таблиц. Т.е. скрипт может создавать какую угодно одну таблицу. Возможно имеет смысл в запросе возвращать имена таблиц и проверять не только их количество, но и названия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Assert - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) - проверяет условия в модульных тестов с помощью
>   утверждения "Истина/Ложь". Этот класс содержит набор статических методов, которые оценивают
>   логическое условие. Если это условие принимает значение `true`, передает
>   утверждения. Утверждение проверяет предположение истинности для
>   сравниваемых условий. Если проверяемое
>   условие не выполняется, утверждение признается ложным.

Рассмотрим несколько примеров тестов, на основании Вашего кода в вопросе с небольшими пояснениями и отступлениями.

---

Тест с использованием [метода Assert.AreEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx) (Метод проверяет, что указанные значения равны). Тест будет считаться завершенным успешно, если `result` будет равен `0`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodAssertAreEqual()
{
    var result = 0; // предположим, что мы получили это значение
    Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
}
```

---

Тест с использованием [метода Assert.AreNotEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.arenotequal.aspx) (Метод проверяет, что указанные значения не равны). Тест будет считаться завершенным успешно, если `result` не будет равен `1`, к примеру `0` - успешное завершение теста:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodAssertAreNotEqual()
{
    var result = 0; // предположим, что мы получили это значение
    Assert.AreNotEqual(1, result);
}
```

---

Также рассмотрим ситуацию, когда во время выполнения метода возникает исключение, которое является ожидаемым. К примеру передали в метод параметр, который вызывает исключение. Для этого нам поможет аттрибут [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx). Пример кода:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
public void TestExpectedException()
{
    var result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(0); // передадим плохой параметр
}
```

Просто предположим, что если в метод `server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar` передать `0`, то должно возникнуть исключение, если у теста будет аттрибут [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx), то тест отработает успешно.

---

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

1. [Assert - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) (здесь можно найти и другие виды `Assert`)
2. [CollectionAssert - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) (утверждения сопоставленные с коллекциями)
3. [Использование классов Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182530.aspx)
4. [Создание и запуск модульных тестов для существующего кода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293546.aspx)

Comment: Вместо `Assert.AreEqual(result, 1)` лучше писать `Assert.AreEqual(1, result)`, поскольку первый параметр метода называется `expected`, а второго — `actual`. То есть вначале должно быть значение, которое должно быть, и лишь затем — значение, которое получилось на самом деле.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, да, Вы несомненно правы. Сейчас внесу правку. *expected - значение, которое ожидается процессом модульного теста*